# How to upload files to Amazon S3 (official SDK) that are larger than 5 MB (approx)?

Tags: .net, amazon-s3

I am using the latest version of the official Amazon S3 SDK (1.0.14.1) to create a backup tool.  So far everything works correctly if the size of the file I'm uploading is below 5 MB, but when any of the files is above 5 MB the upload fails with the following exception:

> System.Net.WebException: The request
>   was aborted: The request was canceled.
>   ---> System.IO.IOException: Cannot close stream until all bytes are
>   written.    at
>   System.Net.ConnectStream.CloseInternal(Boolean
>   internalCall, Boolean aborting)    ---
>   End of inner exception stack trace ---
>   at
>   Amazon.S3.AmazonS3Client.ProcessRequestError(String
>   actionName, HttpWebRequest request,
>   WebException we, HttpWebResponse
>   errorResponse, String requestAddr,
>   WebHeaderCollection& respHdrs, Type t)
>   at
>   Amazon.S3.AmazonS3Client.Invoke[T](S3Request
>   userRequest)    at
>   Amazon.S3.AmazonS3Client.PutObject(PutObjectRequest
>   request)    at
>   BackupToolkit.S3Module.UploadFile(String
>   sourceFileName, String
>   destinationFileName) in
>   W:\code\AutoBackupTool\BackupToolkit\S3Module.cs:line
>   88    at
>   BackupToolkit.S3Module.UploadFiles(String
>   sourceDirectory) in
>   W:\code\AutoBackupTool\BackupToolkit\S3Module.cs:line
>   108

**Note**: 5 MB is roughly the boundary of failure, it can be slightly lower or anything higher

I am assuming that the connection is timing out and the stream is being automatically closed before the file upload completes.

I've tried to find a way to set a long timeout (but I can't find the option in either `AmazonS3` or `AmazonS3Config`).

Any ideas on how to increase the time-out (like an application wide setting I can use) or is it unrelated to a timeout issue?

---

*Code:*

```
var s3Client = AWSClientFactory.CreateAmazonS3Client(AwsAccessKey, AwsSecretKey);

var putObjectRequest = new PutObjectRequest {

    BucketName            = Bucket,
    FilePath              = sourceFileName,
    Key                   = destinationFileName,
    MD5Digest             = md5Base64,
    GenerateMD5Digest     = true
};

using (var upload = s3Client.PutObject(putObjectRequest)) {  }
```

Answer (score 43, accepted):

**Updated answer:**

I recently updated one of my projects that uses the Amazon AWS .NET SDK (to version **1.4.1.0**) and in this version there are two improvements that did not exist when I wrote the original answer here.

1. You can now set `Timeout` to `-1` to have an infinite time limit for the put operation.
2. There is now an extra property on `PutObjectRequest` called `ReadWriteTimeout` which can be set (in milliseconds) to timeout on the stream read/write level opposed to the entire put operation level.

So my code now looks like this:

```
var putObjectRequest = new PutObjectRequest {

    BucketName            = Bucket,
    FilePath              = sourceFileName,
    Key                   = destinationFileName,
    MD5Digest             = md5Base64,
    GenerateMD5Digest     = true,
    Timeout               = -1,
    ReadWriteTimeout      = 300000     // 5 minutes in milliseconds
};
```

**Original answer:**

---

I managed to figure out the answer...

Before posting the question I had explored `AmazonS3` and `AmazonS3Config` but not `PutObjectRequest`.

Inside `PutObjectRequest` there is a `Timeout` property (set in milliseconds).  I have successfully used this to upload the larger files (note: setting it to 0 doesn't remove the timeout, you need to specify a positive number of miliseconds... I've gone for 1 hour).

This works fine:

```
var putObjectRequest = new PutObjectRequest {

    BucketName            = Bucket,
    FilePath              = sourceFileName,
    Key                   = destinationFileName,
    MD5Digest             = md5Base64,
    GenerateMD5Digest     = true,
    Timeout               = 3600000
};
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm now using this as well.  But between you and me don't you feel like this is a hack, I understand it uses HTTP, but there's gotta be a way to keep the connection alive for the duration of the upload or download no matter how big it is, because supposing your file takes longer than an hour to upload, you're stuffed. similar to how there seems to be no restriction on upping or downloading a file normally over the web?

Comment: @GONeale - Yep it would be good to have the freedom to set `Timeout = 0`... or perhaps a timeout bound to data transfer rate.  With an `IdleTimeout` setting we could set it to fail after 10 minutes if 0 bytes have been transferred during that time.  It's also worth noting that Amazon have announced some big changes to S3s upload feature set (http://aws.typepad.com/aws/2010/11/amazon-s3-multipart-upload.html) - definitely worth checking out as it's already been added to the AWS/S3 .NET SDK.

Comment: @GONeale - BTW, I just updated my answer as the Amazon SDK has been updated.  Not sure which version saw these improvements for the first time, but I know that version 1.4.1.0 has them.  See my updated answer for more details! Hope it helps!

Answer (score 10):

I've been having similar problems to this and started to use the TransferUtility class to perform multi part uploads.

At the moment this code is working. I did have problems when the timeout was set too low though!

```
                var request = new TransferUtilityUploadRequest()
                .WithBucketName(BucketName)
                .WithFilePath(sourceFile.FullName)
                .WithKey(key)
                .WithTimeout(100 * 60 * 60 * 1000)
                .WithPartSize(10 * 1024 * 1024)
                .WithSubscriber((src, e) =>
                {
                    Console.CursorLeft = 0;
                    Console.Write("{0}: {1} of {2}    ", sourceFile.Name, e.TransferredBytes, e.TotalBytes);
                });
            utility.Upload(request);
```

As I'm typing this, I have a 4GB upload taking place and it's already got further through than ever before!

Comment: Thanks - solved the problem, also if anyone needs it some alternative eventhanlding code below (along with a method to get percentage upload on the file)

Answer (score 7):

AWS SDK for .NET has **two main APIs** to work with Amazon S3.Both are able to upload large and small files on S3.

**1. Low-level API :**

> The low-level API uses the same pattern used for other service
>   low-level APIs in the SDK.There is a client object called
>   **AmazonS3Client** that implements the IAmazonS3 interface.It contains
>   *methods for each of the service operations exposed by S3.*
>
> Namespace : **Amazon.S3, Amazon.S3.Model**

```
// Step 1 : 
AmazonS3Config s3Config = new AmazonS3Config();
s3Config.RegionEndpoint = GetRegionEndPoint();

// Step 2 :
using(var client = new AmazonS3Client(My_AWSAccessKey, My_AWSSecretKey, s3Config) )
{
    // Step 3 :
    PutObjectRequest request = new PutObjectRequest();
    request.Key = My_key;
    request.InputStream = My_fileStream;
    request.BucketName = My_BucketName;

    // Step 4 : Finally place object to S3
    client.PutObject(request);
}
```

**2. TransferUtility :**  (I would recommend using this API)

> The TransferUtility runs on top of the low-level API. For putting and
>   getting objects into S3, It is a
>   simple interface for handling the most common uses of S3. The biggest
>   benefit comes with putting objects. For example, TransferUtility
>   detects if a file is large and switches into multipart upload mode.
>
> Namespace : **Amazon.S3.Transfer**

```
// Step 1 : Create "Transfer Utility" (replacement of old "Transfer Manager")
TransferUtility fileTransferUtility =
     new TransferUtility(new AmazonS3Client(Amazon.RegionEndpoint.USEast1));

// Step 2 : Create Request object
TransferUtilityUploadRequest uploadRequest =
    new TransferUtilityUploadRequest
    {
        BucketName = My_BucketName,
        FilePath = My_filePath, 
        Key = My_keyName
    };

// Step 3 : Event Handler that will be automatically called on each transferred byte 
uploadRequest.UploadProgressEvent +=
    new EventHandler<UploadProgressArgs>
        (uploadRequest_UploadPartProgressEvent);

static void uploadRequest_UploadPartProgressEvent(object sender, UploadProgressArgs e)
{    
    Console.WriteLine("{0}/{1}", e.TransferredBytes, e.TotalBytes);
}

// Step 4 : Hit upload and send data to S3
fileTransferUtility.Upload(uploadRequest);
```

Answer (score 6):

Nick Randell has got the right idea on this, further to his post here's another example with some alternative eventhandling, and a method to get percentage completed for the uploaded file:

```
        private static string WritingLargeFile(AmazonS3 client, int mediaId, string bucketName, string amazonKey, string fileName, string fileDesc, string fullPath)
    {
        try
        {

            Log.Add(LogTypes.Debug, mediaId, "WritingLargeFile: Create TransferUtilityUploadRequest");
            var request = new TransferUtilityUploadRequest()
                .WithBucketName(bucketName)
                .WithKey(amazonKey)
                .WithMetadata("fileName", fileName)
                .WithMetadata("fileDesc", fileDesc)
                .WithCannedACL(S3CannedACL.PublicRead)
                .WithFilePath(fullPath)
                .WithTimeout(100 * 60 * 60 * 1000) //100 min timeout
                .WithPartSize(5 * 1024 * 1024); // Upload in 5MB pieces 

            request.UploadProgressEvent += new EventHandler<UploadProgressArgs>(uploadRequest_UploadPartProgressEvent);

            Log.Add(LogTypes.Debug, mediaId, "WritingLargeFile: Create TransferUtility");
            TransferUtility fileTransferUtility = new TransferUtility(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AWSAccessKey"], ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AWSSecretKey"]);

            Log.Add(LogTypes.Debug, mediaId, "WritingLargeFile: Start Upload");
            fileTransferUtility.Upload(request);

            return amazonKey;
        }
        catch (AmazonS3Exception amazonS3Exception)
        {
            if (amazonS3Exception.ErrorCode != null &&
                (amazonS3Exception.ErrorCode.Equals("InvalidAccessKeyId") ||
                amazonS3Exception.ErrorCode.Equals("InvalidSecurity")))
            {
                Log.Add(LogTypes.Debug, mediaId, "Please check the provided AWS Credentials.");
            }
            else
            {
                Log.Add(LogTypes.Debug, mediaId, String.Format("An error occurred with the message '{0}' when writing an object", amazonS3Exception.Message));
            }
            return String.Empty; //Failed
        }
    }

    private static Dictionary<string, int> uploadTracker = new Dictionary<string, int>();
    static void uploadRequest_UploadPartProgressEvent(object sender, UploadProgressArgs e)
    {
        TransferUtilityUploadRequest req = sender as TransferUtilityUploadRequest;          
        if (req != null)
        {
            string fileName = req.FilePath.Split('\\').Last();
            if (!uploadTracker.ContainsKey(fileName))
                uploadTracker.Add(fileName, e.PercentDone);

            //When percentage done changes add logentry:
            if (uploadTracker[fileName] != e.PercentDone)
            {
                uploadTracker[fileName] = e.PercentDone;
                Log.Add(LogTypes.Debug, 0, String.Format("WritingLargeFile progress: {1} of {2} ({3}%) for file '{0}'", fileName, e.TransferredBytes, e.TotalBytes, e.PercentDone));
            }
        }

    }

    public static int GetAmazonUploadPercentDone(string fileName)
    {
        if (!uploadTracker.ContainsKey(fileName))
            return 0;

        return uploadTracker[fileName];
    }
```

Comment: Is your timeout meant to be for 100 hours?

Comment: Hi - yeah you're right the timeout in the example is 100hrs in milliseconds, do 100 * 60 * 1000 to get the intended 100 mins.

Answer (score 1):

see this topic here [How to upload a file to amazon S3 super easy using c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25814972/how-to-upload-a-file-to-amazon-s3-super-easy-using-c-sharp/25814973#25814973) including a demo project to download.
it is high level using AWS sdk .net 3.5 (and higher) it can be utilised using the following code :

```
    // preparing our file and directory names
        string fileToBackup = @"d:\mybackupFile.zip" ; // test file
        string myBucketName = "mys3bucketname"; //your s3 bucket name goes here
        string s3DirectoryName = "justdemodirectory";
        string s3FileName = @"mybackupFile uploaded in 12-9-2014.zip";
        AmazonUploader myUploader = new AmazonUploader();
        myUploader.sendMyFileToS3(fileToBackup, myBucketName, s3DirectoryName, s3FileName);
```