# transferring large files to Amazon S3 using C# - Request aborted and Canceled

Tags: c#, amazon-s3

I am trying to upload a large file to Amazon S3.  I first used the `PutObject` and it worked fine but took about 5 hours to upload a 2GB file.  So I read some online suggestions and tried it with the `TransferUtility`.

I have increased the timeout but this TransferUtility API always give me `"The request was aborted. The request was canceled."` error.

code sample:

```
public void UploadWithMultiPart(string BucketName, string s3_key, string fileName)
{
    var fileTransferUtility = new Amazon.S3.Transfer.TransferUtility(_accessKey, _secretKey);
    var request = new Amazon.S3.Transfer.TransferUtilityUploadRequest()
        .WithBucketName(BucketName)
        .WithKey(s3_key)
        .WithFilePath(fileName)
        .WithTimeout(60*60*1000*100)
        .WithPartSize(1024 * 1024 * 100)
        .WithCannedACL(S3CannedACL.PublicRead)
        .WithStorageClass(S3StorageClass.ReducedRedundancy);

    request.Timeout = 60*60*1000*100;

    fileKey = s3_key;

    request.UploadProgressEvent += new EventHandler<UploadProgressArgs>(uploadRequest_UploadPartProgressEvent);

    //.with = 30000
    // .AddHeader("x-amz-acl", "public-read")

    fileTransferUtility.Upload(request);
}

public void Upload(string BucketName, string s3_key, string fileName)
{
    Amazon.S3.Model.PutObjectRequest request = new Amazon.S3.Model.PutObjectRequest();
    request.WithBucketName(BucketName);
    request.WithKey(s3_key);
    request.WithFilePath(fileName);
    request.Timeout = -1;
    request.ReadWriteTimeout = 30000;
    request.AddHeader("x-amz-acl", "public-read"); 

    s3Client.PutObject(request);
}
```

Comment: Have you already gone through this solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3871430/how-to-upload-files-to-amazon-s3-official-sdk-that-are-larger-than-5-mb-appro  ?

Comment: It wasnt that particular post; but similar. I ended up using the TransferUtility + the ConfigOptions to split the parts into the correct size

Answer (score 1):

Try This

```
private TransferUtility transferUtility;
transferUtility = new TransferUtility(awsAccessKey, awsSecretKey);

AsyncCallback callback = new AsyncCallback(UploadComplete);


var putObjectRequest = new Amazon.S3.Transfer.TransferUtilityUploadRequest()
{
   FilePath = filePath,
   BucketName = awsBucketName,
   Key = awsFilePath,
   ContentType = contentType,
   StorageClass = S3StorageClass.ReducedRedundancy,
   ServerSideEncryptionMethod = ServerSideEncryptionMethod.AES256,
   CannedACL = S3CannedACL.Private
};
IAsyncResult ar = transferUtility.BeginUpload(putObjectRequest, callback, null);
ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(c =>
{
   transferUtility.EndUpload(ar);
});
```