# How do I get the access key and the secret key of my S3 Amazon account?

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, visual-studio, web-services, amazon-s3

I have an AWS account and I wish to upload a file using C# and Visual Studio. To do so, I am using [a tutorial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25814972/how-to-upload-a-file-to-amazon-s3-super-easy-using-c-sharp) that I found right here on StackOverflow that requires an Access key and a Secret key.

I tried to create it in the console but it said that I do not have permissions. How do I get those keys? Is there some tutorial that is updated about this topic?

Comment: To get your access key ID and secret access Key: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSGettingStartedGuide/AWSCredentials.html

To upload a file to AWS S3: http://www.codelocker.net/30385/dot-net-c-sharp-upload-a-file-to-amazon-aws-s3-with-dot-net-and-c-sharp/

Comment: When I do those steps I find this message:
We encountered the following errors while processing your request:
User: arn:aws:iam::374594064632:user/ggard is not authorized to perform: iam:ListUsers on resource: arn:aws:iam::374594064632:user/

Comment: hm, you should update your question with some code here. What have you tried? In what specific part do you get this message?

Comment: Forget about that, I created a new user and allready have those credentials, but I am following this tutorial http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25814972/how-to-upload-a-file-to-amazon-s3-super-easy-using-c-sharp
But I don't know int the main class what to put in this variables
string s3DirectoryName = "justdemodirectory";
string s3FileName = @"mybackupFile uploaded in 12-9-2014.zip";

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [tutorial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25814972/how-to-upload-a-file-to-amazon-s3-super-easy-using-c-sharp) you are using assumes that the application has access to AWS IAM credentials.

The credentials can be provided in several ways:

- By running the code on an Amazon EC2 instance that was launched with a **Role**
- By storing AWS credentials in a **configuration file**
- By storing AWS credentials in **Environment Variables**

For details, see:

- AWS .NET SDK [Configuring AWS Credentials](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSdkDocsNET/V3/DeveloperGuide/net-dg-config-creds.html)
- Security Blog [A New and Standardized Way to Manage Credentials in the AWS SDKs](https://blogs.aws.amazon.com/security/post/Tx3D6U6WSFGOK2H/A-New-and-Standardized-Way-to-Manage-Credentials-in-the-AWS-SDKs)

Comment: Man I have serious problemas about uploading the file to amazon because when I create an instance of the AmazonS3 object, doesn't recognize, I guess is something about the libraries and compatibility between them. help me pls!!

Comment: @dayanrr91 Please post a separate question with more details, such as what you were attempting, code samples and error messages so that we can assist you.