# Upload a generated pdf to amazon S3

Tags: c#, amazon-s3

I'm generating a pdf using itextsharp. I then want to upload that file directly to amazon S3.

Previously when I was uploading a file I could use this and get the input stream of that file. Like so:

```
            AmazonS3Config S3Config = new AmazonS3Config
            {
                RegionEndpoint = RegionEndpoint.USEast1, //its default region set by amazon
            };

            AmazonS3Client client;
            using (client = new Amazon.S3.AmazonS3Client(_awsAccessKey, _awsSecretKey, S3Config))
            {
                var request = new PutObjectRequest()
                {
                    BucketName = _bucketName,
                    CannedACL = S3CannedACL.PublicRead,
                    Key = string.Format("UPLOADS/{0}", file.FileName),
                    InputStream = file.InputStream
                };

                client.PutObject(request);
            }
```

I haven't been able to find a way to get an input stream from my generated pdf I did read I could recreate the file and read it back, but I could't get that to work.

Edit: Adding code used to generate pdf

```
using (var ms = new System.IO.MemoryStream())
            {
                var document = new Document(PageSize.A4, 20f, 10f, 30f, 0f);
                {
                    PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, ms);
                    document.Open();
                    try
                    {

                        Paragraph header = new Paragraph("Test Document");
                        document.Add(header);


                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("{0} Exception caught.", ex);
                }
                finally
                {
                    document.Close();
                    byte[] bytes = ms.ToArray();
                    ms.Close();

                    Response.Clear();
                    Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
                    Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=Contract for cancellation of " + order.OrderID + ".pdf");
                    Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
                    Response.Buffer = true;
                    Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
                    Response.BinaryWrite(bytes);
                    Response.End();
                }
```

Would really appreciate any help on this

Comment: Can you please provide some more code on how you are getting the file and as far as I know the `PutObjectRequest` requires a file path not an `InputStream`

Comment: @Abdul Samad It uses a file path if the file is stored locally on your computer and you know the location. I was uploading the file which then gets saved to a HttpPostedFileBase file, and you then upload using the input stream. The file was generated with itextsharp. will edit question to include that code

Comment: the best and most feasible approach is to save the posted file to a temp directory and upload the file using its path. So you don't want to save it and upload it directly?

Comment: I would not mind saving it to a temp location but was experiencing issues with that. The file was corrupted somehow, and I don't understand enough to troubleshoot it

Comment: I recently answered a similar question. Have a look at it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46084082/drag-and-drop-upload-to-aws-s3-using-asp-net-mvc). I would suggest save the file to a  temp directory and use its path to upload. You can save the file by `File.SaveAs(filePath)` and you can get a temp folder by `Path.GetTempPath()`.