# office365 outlook mail attachments to s3

Tags: amazon-s3, office365, devops, aws-sdk, office365api

how to sync office 365 outlook mails with attachments to AWS S3 automatically? it must be on server or some microsoft app or some lambda function. I don't want to do it via pc

I tried to find some connectors but without luck

Answer (score 0):

There is no ready-made or built-in tools for that. You may consider creating a script or application for doing that using [Graph API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/use-the-api) or EWS. At least using these APIs you can get attachments in Outlook for further uploading to the web server.

See [How to upload a file to amazon S3 super easy using c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25814972/how-to-upload-a-file-to-amazon-s3-super-easy-using-c-sharp).

Comment: like to make lambda function + graph webhook and when a new message will arrive to post to lambda?